# Use proxy on Firefox, but not for https

Tags: firefox, proxy, https

My company uses a proxy, but does allow https directly. Don't ask me why.

I tried to add an exception to the proxy settings, but `https://*` [does not work](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=260883). I also tried to disable "Use this proxy server for all protocols" and leaved SSL blank, but it does not work either.

For now the only solution I found is to install [Proxy Selector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/proxy-selector/) and switch to Direct when I need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [PAC file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config).

Something like this should do the trick:

```
if (url.substring(0, 6) == "https:")
{
    return "DIRECT";
}
else
{
    return "PROXY your.proxy.com:8080";
}
```